# Invoke-RESTMethod PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the Invoke-Restmethod to call a set of API's, but it fails with the below error, i have also posted the same json format, can some let me know what could be wrong ?

```
    ### Ignore TLS/SSL errors
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
public bool CheckValidationResult(
ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
return true;
}}
"@

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12


#Create URL string for Invoke-RestMethod
$urlsend = 'https://' + 'vrslcm-01a.corp.local/lcm/api/v1/' + '/login'


#Credential

$Username = "admin@localhost"
$password = "VMware1!"

$basicAuth = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($Username):$Password"))
    $headers = @{

        "description"= "Testing Authentication"
    }

    $body = @{
                    $raw= '{\n\t\"username\": \"admin@localhost\",\n\t\"password\": \"vmware\"\n}'
                    "mode"= $raw
            }

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri $urlsend -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

[image]

Here is the sample jSON which iam trying to invoke via powershell, it consists of the header and the body. I need to understand how we could call the same jSON POSTMAN example via the PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

```
"item": [
        {
            "name": "authorization",
            "description": "",
            "item": [
                {
                    "name": "Login",
                    "event": [
                        {
                            "listen": "test",
                            "script": {
                                "type": "text/javascript",
                                "exec": [
                                    "var response=JSON.parse(responseBody)",
                                    "postman.setEnvironmentVariable(\"token\", response.token)"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "request": {
                        "url": "{{Server}}/lcm/api/v1/login",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Content-Type",
                                "value": "application/json",
                                "description": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "body": {
                            "mode": "raw",
                            "raw": "{\n\t\"username\": \"admin@localhost\",\n\t\"password\": \"vmware\"\n}"
                        },
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "response": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Logout",
                    "request": {
                        "url": "{{Server}}/lcm/api/v1/logout",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "x-xenon-auth-token",
                                "value": "{{token}}",
                                "description": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "body": {},
                        "description": ""
                    },
                    "response": []
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Could you fix it? Was any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `$raw` to a hashtable like

```
$raw = @{
    username=$Username
    password=$Password
}
```

add this hashtable to the `$body` hashtable

```
$body = @{         
    mode= $raw
}
```

but now it still is a hashtable the api cannot use. thus convert it to json like

```
$jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

using `$jsonBody` should then work when used like

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri $urlsend -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: I tried this - but get the below error - Invoke-RestMethod :
{"message":"forbidden","statusCode":500,"documentKind":"com:vmware:xenon:common:ServiceErrorResponse","errorCode":0}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri $urlsend -Headers $headers -Body  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc

Comment: so the post was successful but the authentication did fail. please read the docs how to authenticate https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Suite/2017/com.vmware.vrsuite.lcm_api_12.doc/GUID-65B6DB81-7ED5-4CAD-AE05-680B0A5DE03A.html also .. did you check if https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VMware.PowerCLI has cmdlets for what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states, the problem is your hash definition.

> A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.

PowerShell tries to evaluate $raw as a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) key. Since it hasn't been defined before it is null and fails because null is not allowed. Try it like this:

```
$raw= '{\n\t\"username\": \"admin@localhost\",\n\t\"password\": \"vmware\"\n}'

$body = @{         
    "mode"= $raw
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but got the below error    Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Unparseable JSON body: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
STRING at line 1 column 1 path
$","statusCode":400,"documentKind":"com:vmware:xenon:common:ServiceErrorResponse","errorCode":0}
At line:1 char:1